# Is there a closed form for $\sum1/(n2^n(2^n)!)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

A while ago I had a dream, the series you see below appeared in front of my eyes

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{n 2^n (2^n)! }$$

Do you think it is possible to find a closed form of it?

Comment: Does Goddess Namagiri whisper this series to you in your dream?

Comment: @Tunk-Fey No. I also dreamt this series before meeting it in my research $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \arcsin\left(\frac{1}{e^n}\right)$$

Comment: What did you consume before going to sleep?

Comment: It obviously converges. The terms get small quickly - the 4th term is less than $10^{-15}$ and the 5th less than $10^{-37}$. Isn't an approximation to 3 terms good enough?

Comment: ISC and WA do not yield any "feasible" results.

Comment: Are you sure it was a dream ?

Comment: ISC reports nothing for 0.2552093667328 so certainly it is not a "well known" closed form.  I think "the number is transcendental" is more likely to be proved than a "closed form" for it.

Comment: You should post $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \arcsin\left(\frac{1}{e^n}\right)$$ It is a very nice one. May I wish you nice and good dreams (don't come back with another nightmare, please !). Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici :-)))

Answer (score 0):

> *Do **you** think it is possible to find a closed form of it?*

No. ***I*** don't. If for *no* other reason, then merely because I am utterly unaware of **any** non-trivial

series of the form $\displaystyle\sum_{n=\ldots}^\infty\frac{\ldots}{\ldots(a^n)!\ldots}$ to have a **known** closed form.

Comment: Yes, I believe we can go beyond imagination.

Comment: @Chris'ssis: And one day we might. :-) But, to my knowledge, that day is yet to come.